# Ionic 5 Angular LoadingController Uncaught (in promise): overlay does not exist

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am working with ionic 5, and trying to use ion LoadingController with resolvers.

At first, the problem I had was that `loadingController.dismiss()` was called before `loadingController.create()` finished, so I followed the instructions here:
[Ionic 4: "Loading Controller" dismiss() is called before present() which will keep spinner without dismissing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574448/ionic-4-loading-controller-dismiss-is-called-before-present-which-will-ke).

So, I created a Service to show and dismiss the loader like this:

```
  export class LoaderService {

  isLoading = false;

  constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) { }

  async present() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    return await this.loadingController.create().then(a => {
      a.present().then(() => {
        if (!this.isLoading) {
          a.dismiss();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  async dismiss() {
    if (this.isLoading) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      return await this.loadingController.dismiss();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And I call it in the app.component

```
 constructor(
    private platform: Platform, private loaderService: LoaderService,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private languageService: LanguageService,
    private appDataService: AppDataService,
    private popOverCtrl: PopoverController,
    private auth: AuthService, private router: Router
  ) {

      this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
        switch(true){
          case event instanceof NavigationStart: {
            this.loaderService.present();
            break;
          }

          case event instanceof NavigationEnd:
          case event instanceof NavigationCancel:
          case event instanceof NavigationError: {
            this.loaderService.dismiss();
            break;
          }
          default: {
            break;
          }
        }
      })
      this.initializeApp();
  }
```

But I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: Isn't your problem related to the fact that your service is call from the constructor ? as long as the app is not ready you cannot use safely Ionic components.

Comment: I moved the service call to the ngInit of app.component and same result

Comment: And in platform.ready ?

Comment: Tried, and same result.

Comment: And what if you remove the await in 'return await' ? Just return the promise.

Comment: I've just tried It, and the issue persist. It seems that removing the await had no efect.

Comment: @alvardo did you find any solution

Comment: @Ajt not really, I was forced to used a fixed Time out

Answer (score 1):

**Uncaught (in promise): overlay does not exist** is a very generic error and can appear in multiple situations. In general, it occurs when trying to resolve a promise and it does not exist.

The solution is quite simple, we are trying to close a modal or the loading component when it has not been created yet.

You should use the ionic lifecycle (see [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)) to be able to initialize the LoadingController before closing it:

- ngOnInit
- ionViewWillEnter
- ionViewDidEnter
- ionViewWillLeave
- ionViewDidLeave
- ngOnDestroy

```js
ngOnInit() { // or you can use ionViewWillEnter()
    this.loaderService.present(); }

ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.loaderService.dismiss();
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I am using resolvers to pre-fetch data for the view, so your solution won't be useful to me. Nevertheless, I tried it and the error persist.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';



@Injectable()
export class  SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  isLoading = false;
  loaderToShow: any;
  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController
    ) { }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      this.present();
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
                map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                  this.dismiss();
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        console.log('event--->>>', event);
                    }
                    return event;
                }));
  }

  public loader:any
  async present() {
    this.loader = await this.loadingController.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      message: 'Please wait...',
      duration: 2000
    });
    await this.loader.present();
  }


    async dismiss() {
      let topLoader = await this.loadingController.getTop();
      while (topLoader) {
        if (!(await topLoader.dismiss())) {
          // throw new Error('Could not dismiss the topmost loader. Aborting...');
          break
        }
        topLoader = await this.loadingController.getTop();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea using Interceptor, but dismiss is somehow never called

Answer (score 0):

Calling the loader in a timeout function solves it for me. All calls to the loader function are made from a shared service.

```
  presentLoading(duration?,text?) {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.startLoader(duration,text);
      },2000)
    })
  }
  async startLoader(duration?,text?){
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      message: (text)?('Please wait...'+text):'Please wait...',
      duration: (duration)?duration:''
    });
    await loading.present();

    const { role, data } = await loading.onDidDismiss();
  }
```

and ensure you check if the loader is active before closing it

```
dismissLoader(){
    this.loadingController.getTop().then(v => v ? this.doStopLoader() : null);
  }
  doStopLoader(){
    this.loadingController.dismiss();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by running your app in the browser, particularly if using browser device emulation (Called "device toolbar" in Chrome and Responsive Mode in Firefox). Try disabling device toolbar (Ctrl+Shift+M) or running your app on a physical device or use a proper Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

```
 async showLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: 'Waiting',
    });
    loading.present();
    loading.addEventListener('ionLoadingDidPresent', (event: any) => {
      console.log('ionLoadingDidPresent')
     //here to do longtime task and close dialog and you will not meet close before open problem
    });
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).